# How can I absolutely position a related image_tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, css-position

I'm super new to rails and javascript, I have a table of venues with each belonging to a type and an area. They are displayed as partials on the index page and also each has its own icon on a map to the left of the screen.

I have just added a new table of mapicons which just holds an image uploaded using paperclip to my app so each venuetype has a differant icon. This all works fine however the javascript I was using to place the icons on the map breaks when I include the new mapicon.

**working mapicon placement (_venue.html.erb)**

```
<%= link_to venue do %>
  <div class="venue_partial">    
    <span class="venue_partial_name"><%= venue.name %></span>    
    <div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" class="venue_map_icon" style="position:absolute;"></div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.left= "<%= venue.iconleftpx %>px";
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.top= "<%= venue.icontoppx %>px";
</script>
```

Displays the map icon correctly on the map but as black stars as I have set in the css.

**broken mapicon placement (_venue.html.erb)**

```
<%= link_to venue do %>
  <div class="venue_partial">    
    <span class="venue_partial_name"><%= venue.name %></span>    
    <div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" <%= image_tag venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon), :style => "position:absolute;", :class => "venue_map_icon" %></div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.left= "<%= venue.iconleftpx %>px";
  document.getElementById("venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>").style.top= "<%= venue.icontoppx %>px";
</script>
```

Displays the correct mapicons that I uploaded and assigned to each venuetype but they are positioned at the top right corner of their venue partial and not on the map to the left of the screen.

Hope I've asked this well, any clarification needed please ask. Thanks for any help its much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Heres a couple of screenshots I hope will help, The first is how the mapicons are currently. The venue partials show as Tester1, Tester2 etc with a large coloured icon to the left of the name, the grayed lettering under the name is the type (Type 1, 2 or 3). And the map icons are the black stars to the left positioned absolutely with the top and left values taken from their respective venue records.

[image]

The second screenshot is when I change the code as shown above, the partials show the same but the mapicons instead of being black stars show correctly as smaller coloured squares but aren't positioning correctly. They are sticking to the top right corner of their own venue partials.

[image]

This is what I want it to display as: (this is a mocked-up image)

[image]

The CSS for the mapicons is just:

```
.venue_map_icon {
width: 19px;
height: 18px;
padding: none;
margin: none;
background-image:url(/images/mapicon.png);
border: none;
}

  .venue_map_icon:hover {
  background-image:url(/images/mapicon_hover.png);
  }
```

**Model relationships**

Venues

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :venuetype
end
```

Venuetypes

```
class Venuetype < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venues
  belongs_to :mapicon
  has_attached_file :icon,
    :styles => {
      :thumb=> "100x100>",
      :small  => "150x150>",
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :large =>   "400x400>" },
      :default_url => '/images/noimage.png'
end
```

Mapicons

```
class Mapicon < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :venuetypes
  has_attached_file :mapicon,
    :styles => { 
      :large => "640x480", 
      :medium => "300x300", 
      :thumb => "100x100", 
      :mapicon => "20x20" }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error!

What was:

```
<div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" <%= image_tag venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon), :style => "position:absolute;", :class => "venue_map_icon" %></div>
```

Should be:

```
<div id="venue_map_icon_<%= venue.id %>" style="position:absolute;" <%= image_tag (venue.venuetype.mapicon.mapicon.url(:mapicon)), :class => "venue_map_icon" %></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see other CSS for your elements, but note that `position: absolute` is only absolute with respect to the "nearest ancestor" that has a position that is not the default type (the `static`).

So, in your case, you may want to make

```
<div class="venue_partial">
```

to have `position: relative`, but just don't set the `top` or `left` so that it stays where it is.  If you need to make it absolute with respect to a different ancestor, then make the appropriate element `position: relative` instead.

Comment: @動靜能量, thanks for having a look, the venue_partials are floated to the left and just stack up filling the right side of the screen. The venue_map_icon element is positioned absolutely and takes the top and left values from the venue database (each record has a icontoppx and iconleftpx fields). Adding position:absolute to the venue_partial class just causes them all to stack ontop on each other.

Answer (score 0):

Again, it's tough without seeing your CSS, but I used this bit of code for my own "custom" positioning that can change with different resolution or even with the onRefresh event

```
function fixBox() {

    var child = document.getElementById('dropdown_child');
    var parent = document.getElementById('dropdown_parent');
    var curLeft = 0;
    if(parent.offsetParent) {
        do {
          curLeft += parent.offsetLeft;
        } while(parent = parent.offsetParent)

    }
    parent = document.getElementById('dropdown_parent');
    var w = child.offsetWidth - parent.offsetWidth;
    var x = curLeft - w;
    child.style.left = x;



}
```

Modify freely for your own use, in this particular case, it makes a child div right-aligned with a parent div. If I'm understanding correctly, this should help your case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have edited my question with a couple pics to show what I mean, I think its an error in my code change as it works fine without the change (using the css styled mapicons)

Comment: @Dave I suppose I'm still having trouble understanding your concept here... What is the reason for changing the code and can you mock up a screenshot of what your result should look like in the end?

Comment: I've added an image of what I want it to render as, the reason for the code change is to allow each venuetype to have a unique mapicon, so all bars have a map icon of a glass or all cinemas could have an icon of a reel or whatnot. I'll add in at the bottom a better description of my relationships.